# What's the efficiency difference between these (almost identical) conditions

Tags: python

I was given a challenge by a friend to build an efficient Fibonacci function in python. So I started testing around different ways of doing the recursion (I do not have high math skills to think of a complex algorithm, and please **do not show me an efficient Fibonacci function**, that is not the question).

Then I tried two different solutions:

Solution 1:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n > 1:
        return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
    return 1
```

Solution 2:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
```

Then, I ran this for each:

```
res = map(fibo, range(35))
print res
```

Now, I suspected there might be an efficiency difference (I can't say why exactly). But I expected a small difference. the results blew me away completely. The difference was **huge**. The first one took 7.5 seconds while the second took a staggering 12.7 (that's almost twice!).

Can anyone explain to me why? Aren't those essentially the same?

Comment: Both are dire. Why calculate more than 35 values? Don't recurse. Loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I can reproduce the difference in running times between the two functions.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Interesting, with `timeit`? Then the jump is taking more time than expected.

Comment: No, by timing `res = map(fibo1, range(35))` and `res = map(fibo2, range(35))` (after writing the functions accordingly). I'm trying `timeit` as well

Comment: @DavidRobinson: and as it turns out, that's because the wrong test is used in the function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Indeed!

Comment: When you ask why two identical parts of code have such a drastic difference in performance, first ask whether they are identical indeed. It's easy to see that even for `n = 1` (!!!) the results will be different.

Comment: Try memoization if you want to make it efficient. Recursion is very slow in Python due to lack of tail-call optimization and should be avoided. Just by looping instead of recursing and using memoization, I guarantee you will see much faster results (without needing much "high math skills").

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Yeah I eventually found a very fast solution, but I wasn't asking about that. Yeah I mistakingly did `i < 1` instead of `i < 2` but is that the entire difference? Hmm... I need to tsst this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(not n > 1)` is `(n <= 1)`, re-run the second code with `<=` and you will see that you get similar timings:

```
In [1]: def fibo(n):
   ....:    if n <= 1:
   ....:        return 1
   ....:    return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
   ....: 

In [2]: %timeit map(fibo, range(10))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.2 us per loop

In [3]: def fibo(n):
   ....:    if n > 1:
   ....:        return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
   ....:    return 1
   ....: 

In [4]: %timeit map(fibo, range(10))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.9 us per loop
```

And if you wonder why this makes such a huge difference, when you run `map(fibo, range(35))` you have `14930351` calls to `fibo(1)`. With `(n < 1)`, each `fibo(1)` will make two functions calls (to `fibo(0)` and `fibo(-1)`) and sums the results, quite a few operations!

Comment: By the way, why is there still a difference? Why would one be more efficient than the other? (even so slightly)

Answer (score 8):

> Aren't those essentially the same?

The second function is calculating a higher fibonacci number, so naturally it takes longer:

```
>>> def fibo(n):
...     if n > 1:
...         return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
...     return 1
... 
>>> fibo(10)
89
>>> def fibo(n):
...     if n < 1:
...         return 1
...     return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
... 
>>> fibo(10)
144
```

You likely want `n <= 1` in the second snippet:

```
>>> def fibo(n):
...     if n <= 1:
...         return 1
...     return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
... 
>>> fibo(10)
89
```

Comment: Well then. That was rather funny

Comment: Thanks so much. I gave the rightright answer to Olivier but just because he gave a more full example. I gave you a thumbs up, wish I could give you an answer as well!